# How to change image source based on its class in jQuery, after the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building an image slider in jQuery to bolster my knowledge of the language.  In order to indicate that an image should be shown, I add a "selected" class to that `<img>` tag.  Additionally, in order to indicate that a nav button should be toggled on/off, I add an **active**/**inactive** class to that respective `li`.

Example here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    initPics();
    currentImage = $('.selected').attr('id');


    var navButton = $("li").find("img");
    //show the right image when the nav button is clicked
    $(navButton).on('click',function(){
        $("#"+currentImage).removeClass('selected');
        $("#"+currentImage).addClass('notSelected');

        //change nav button when a different one is clicked
        $('#navigation').children('li').children("img").removeClass('active');
        $('#navigation').children('li').children("img").addClass('inactive');

    });

    if ($("li img").hasClass('active')){
        $(this).find(".active").attr('src','images/button1.png');
    } else {
        $(this).attr('src','images/button2.png');
    }


});
```

**FYI** The HTML that I'm working on looks like this:

**Navigation buttons:**

```
<ul id="navigation">
            <li><img class="inactive" id="1" src="images/button2.png"></li>
```

**Images in slider**

```
<img src="images/slider1.jpg" id="image-1" class="slider selected">
```

---

**The problem:**

Whenever I click a new navigation button and remove the `active` class from the nav buttons and add the `inactive` class, it **should** also change the source of the image from `button1.png` to `button2.png`.  It does change classes from `active` to `inactive` properly, but the `img src` never changes. Why is this the case?

---

**Edit:**
Link to a demo of what I'm talking about: [demo](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/tim5046/projectOdin/blob/master/Javascript/Slider/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the code to change the image inside the `click` function, otherwise it will be executed only one time: when the page loads. And obviously your image will never change anymore.

Here's the code:

```
$(navButton).on('click',function(){
    $("#"+currentImage).removeClass('selected');
    $("#"+currentImage).addClass('notSelected');

    //change nav button when a different one is clicked
    $('#navigation').children('li').children("img").removeClass('active');
    $('#navigation').children('li').children("img").addClass('inactive');

    // change image
    $("li img.active").attr('src','images/button1.png');
    $("li img.inactive").attr('src','images/button2.png');
});
```

Comment: Ah excellent. I had a feeling it was something related to the code only being run once when the page loaded. Thanks!